# Referencing another node's field values

Tags: entities, nodes

I have created a "Customer" node-type. In that, I have a multi-valued field "Addresses" for taking customer's address.

I have another node-type "Order". While creating a new "Order", I want to select the customer from my existing customers. I can do this using entity or node reference. Now, while selecting the customer, I also want to select the customer's address which is present in the "Customer" node-type.

So, how do I do this? How do I reference another node's field values?

Or, is there any other way for this use-case?

Answer (score 1):

[Entity Reference Autofill](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill) does exactly what you want.

> > The Entity reference autofill module gives Entity reference fields an option to populate other form fields with data from selected referenced entities.